# Using email on ruby without having an email

Tags: ruby, sendmail, email

I would like to send an email without having to set up an external email account and without having to set up a server of my own. Ideally I would not have to do anything but enter code into ruby command.

Is there any way to do this?

I couldn't find a clear step by step guide to using email on ruby, can someone point me in the right direction? Please assume that I know nothing. Thanks. I am not using ruby on rails. :-)

I have tried pony, but it would seem that I need an email to send the message from...? I would like to send the message directly from ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. Here are some techniques:

- The return address does not have to be valid, you can make one up. But wouldn't you want the return address to at least be a real one under your control?
- The original, official, IETF way to do this involved looking up the MX or A record for your destination in DNS and then sending the mail via SMTP to that host via A TCP stream on port 25. There are gems that will do this.
- On a server, the above works, but then again, a server should be running its own mail relay with queues and retry and such and so an improvement on the above technique is to just skip the DNS and post the message to localhost:25.
- But if it's a server you don't *need* to speak SMTP, it's just 5 or 10 lines of code to popen() one of the CLI mail agents, which are: sendmail, mailx, or mail.  You can just write your message with `puts()` now.
- If it's not a server (home cable or DSL) or its a virtual server (EC2) then there may be some sort of restrictions on direct mail transmissions. If you operate your own relay somewhere in the cloud on a port number you choose you can get around these restrictions.
- A purely technical solution may not be enough if you send more mail than a blacklist or your cloud provider approves of. The solution to *that* is to engage a third-party mail delivery service. One of their jobs is to social-engineer the blacklist entities and stay in business.